# Cannot create external source with Azure database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I tried to run this SQL script in order to create external source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE Unspsc 
WITH 
( 
    TYPE=RDBMS, 
    LOCATION='myservername.database.windows.net', 
    DATABASE_NAME='Unspsc', 
    CREDENTIAL= VanillaCredential 
)
```

And got the error:

> An external data source conflicting with 'Unspsc' already exists in EDS cache in memory. Use alter step to change the location or credential. Drop and re-create to change the EDS name.

so I altered the DataSource like below:

```
ALTER EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE Unspsc 
SET LOCATION='myservername.database.windows.net', 
    DATABASE_NAME='Unspsc', 
    CREDENTIAL= VanillaCredential
```

I got below error:

> Cannot alter the object 'Unspsc', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

It did work before, I am not sure how I can fix it. Also, I really don't understand what EDS cache in memory is.

Comment: Do you have the "ALTER ANY EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE" permission?

Comment: Yes, I did run it on admin account

Comment: EDS would, at first glance, appear to be E(xternal)D(ata)S(ource). Have you attempted dropping the source before attempting to add it?

Comment: @drediske: Yes, I tried but I got that the source does not exist. What I meant the cache in this exception, and how the cache works with EDS

Answer (score 1):

Scale the database up or down in Azure portal.

While this question is quite old, I can find very little mention of it anywhere on the web, and I could find no solution. Scaling the database apparently empties the EDS cache and then allows you to create an external data source again with that same name it was just previously complaining about in the error message.

I have a databricks notebook that creates an external data source, bulk loads data, and then drops the external data source. I was manually running parts of the notebook, and somehow get the SQL Server into this confused state.

Scaling the database might not be practical for a production database during business hours since it generally kills all connections when it scales, but it could be used in an emergency or during off hours.

Comment: Thank you for this solution but this is a terrible oversight from MSFT.